# Error in jq manual `jq '.[2:4]' <<< abcdefghi`?

Tags: string, bash, jq

The manual says

```
jq '.[2:4]'
   "abcdefghi"
=> "cd"
```

But a run of `jq` prints this:

```
$ jq '.[2:4]' <<< abcdefghi
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
```

Is the manual wrong? Or there is a bug in the program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`abcdefghi` is not a valid JSON string, but `"abcdefghi"` is:

```
$ jq '.[2:4]' <<< '"abcdefghi"'
"cd"
```

If you look at the [jq play example](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=.%5B2%3A4%5D&j=%22abcdefghi%22) linked from the manual, you'll see the double quoted input.

Comment: It seems that `man jq` is not the same as https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/. As I don't find this particular example in the latter.

Comment: @user1424739 It's the second example [here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Array/StringSlice:.[10:15]). And it looks the same both online and in the man page...?

Comment: OK. I see. Thanks.